# Problem related to but different from Sturms Comparison Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $y(x),z(x)$ satisfy $y''+q(x)y=0,z''+Q(x)z=0$ respectively, where $q(x),Q(x)$ are continuous and $Q(x)>q(x)>0$. Then if the intervals $[x_1,x_2],[x_1,x_2^*]$ satisfy

$$
y(x_1)=y(x_2)=0,\quad y(x)>0,x\in(x_1,x_2)\\
z(x_1)=z(x_2^*)=0,\quad z(x)>0,x\in(x_1,x_2^*)
$$

and $y'(x_1)=z'(x_1)$, **prove that**

$$
z(x)<y(x),\qquad \forall x\in(x_1,x_2^*)
$$

From Sturms Comparison Theorem, it's easy to obtain that $x_1<x_2^*<x_2$, but how can we compare the values of $y(x),z(x)$?

I've tried the same technique used in Sturms Comparison Theorem.

$$
\frac{d(y'z-z'y)}{dx}=y''z-z''y=(Q-q)yz
$$

Therefore, $y'z-z'y$ is strictly increasing on $(x_1,x_2^*)$, but I can't get further.

Besiedes, I've seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578778/modified-sturms-comparison-theorem), which proved that $y(x)>z(x)$ does not hold on $(x_1,\infty)$, but it possibly does not provide any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{y}{z} \right)= \frac{zy' - z'y}{z^2}$$
and $zy' - z'y$ is strictly increasing as you shown. Thus
$$zy' - z'y >z(0) y'(0) - z'(0) y(0) = 0,$$
which implies

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{y}{z} > 0.$$

Thus by L'Hospital rule,

$$ \frac{y(x) }{z(x)}> \lim_{x\to x_1}\frac{y(x)}{z(x)} = \lim_{x\to x_1} \frac{y'(x)}{z'(x)} = \frac{y'(x_1)}{z'(x_1)}=1.$$